# Concorrência básica em Erlang

Tags: concorrência, erlang

*Adaptado [desta questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075965/concurrency-in-erlang-and-its-proper-workflow) no stack overflow internacional, cuja resposta é da minha autoria.*

O código seguinte foi dado numa aula. Testámos o código, mas não entendi bem como funciona. Como é que este código cria vários processos, e como é que eles interagem entre si?

```
-module(pingpong).
-compile(export_all).

start_pong() ->
    register(pong, spawn(pingpong,pong,[])).

pong() ->
    receive
        finished ->
            io:format("Pong finished ~n");
        {ping, Ping_Pid} ->
            io:format("i am the receiver ~n"),
        Ping_Pid ! pong,
        pong()
end.

start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
    spawn(pingpong, ping, [3, Pong_Node]).

ping(0, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! finished,
    io:format("Pong finished ~n");

ping(N, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! {ping, self()},
    receive
        pong ->
            io:format("i am the sender ~n")
    end,
    ping(N-1,Pong_Node).
```

Answer (score 4):

Comecemos por ver as duas primeiras linhas.

```
-module(pingpong).
-compile(export_all).
```

A primeira é a declaração do módulo. O seu argumento é um átomo (uma palavra sem aspas, em letra minúscula) que representa o nome dado ao módulo. Adaptado de *Learn You Some Erlang*:

> `-module(Name).`
>   Este é sempre o primeiro atributo (e primeira frase) de um ficheiro, e com bom motivo: é o nome do módulo atual, onde `Name` é um átomo. Este é o nome que irá usar para chamar funções a partir de outros módulos. As chamadas são feitas da forma `M:F(A)`, onde `M` é o nome do módulo, `F` é a função, e `A` os argumentos desta.

A segunda frase diz ao compilador para tornar públicas todas as funções definidas no módulo, ou seja, toda a função *F* que escrever neste módulo poderá ser chamada a partir do exterior, com `pingpong:F`. Isto simplifica o processo de aprendizagem, mas, em geral, não é boa prática tornar todas as funções públicas. Em vez disso, enumere cada função que pretende exportar.

---

Vejamos agora as funções definidas.

```
start_pong() ->
    register(pong, spawn(pingpong,pong,[])).
```

Este é possivelmente o ponto de entrada para o seu código. Compile o módulo, e comece por chamar `pingpong:start_pong().` na consola Erlang, numa instância da máquina virtual (um nodo). O que esta função faz é registar o nome `pong` como identificador para um novo processo que irá ser criado, com `spawn`.

Portanto, `spawn` cria processos Erlang. `spawn` é uma função *built-in* (*BIF*), e por isso não requer que se escreva o nome do módulo no prefixo. Os seus argumentos são `spawn(Modulo, Funcao_Exportada, Lista_de_Argumentos)`, como visto [na documentação](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html).
Voltando a `start_pong`, o que ela realmente faz é criar um processo que correrá a função `pong` deste módulo, sem argumentos, e chamar a este processo `pong`.

---

```
pong() ->
    receive
        finished ->
            io:format("Pong finished ~n");
        {ping, Ping_Pid} ->
            io:format("i am the receiver ~n"),
            Ping_Pid ! pong,
            pong()
    end.
```

O novo processo de `start_pong` vai correr esta função. Todo o processo Erlang tem a sua própria *caixa de correio*. Os processos comunicam entre si deixando mensagens nas caixas de outros. As mensagens podem ser praticamente qualquer coisa, quaisquer dados.

O novo processo entra no bloco `receive`, que lhe diz para pesquisar mensagens na sua caixa de correio, ou para esperar até que haja alguma. Depois usa *pattern matching* para encontrar a ação correspondente à mensagem recebida. Se está habituado a linguagens imperativas comuns, pode ver isto quase como um *switch*.

Se o processo tiver uma mensagem composta pelo átomo `finished`, ele imprime *"Pong finished"* na consola e termina. Se o processo tiver uma mensagem que é um par composto pelo átomo `ping` e um identificador de processo (*pid* - todo o processo tem o seu), então irá executar o código restante desta função.

O `Ping_Pid`, começado por letra maiúscula, diz ao Erlang para guardar numa variável com este nome qualquer que seja o valor que vem no segundo elemento da mensagem. Neste caso, apenas esperamos um *pid*.
Quando entra neste caso, imprime *"i am the receiver"* e envia uma mensagem com o átomo `pong` para o processo identificado pelo `Ping_Pid` - é esta a utilidade do operador `!`. Por fim, a função chama-se recursivamente, para voltar a ir à caixa de correio.

---

A próxima coisa que escreverá na consola, provavelmente noutra instância da máquina virtual, será a chamada a `start_ping`.

```
start_ping(Pong_Node) ->
    spawn(pingpong, ping, [3, Pong_Node]).
```

Como visto antes, o que isto faz é criar um novo processo, que irá correr a função `ping` com argumentos `3` e `Pong_Node`, em que o segundo é o nodo onde o primeiro processo está a correr.

```
ping(0, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! finished,
    io:format("Pong finished ~n");

ping(N, Pong_Node) ->
    {pong, Pong_Node} ! {ping, self()},
    receive
        pong ->
            io:format("i am the sender ~n")
    end,
    ping(N-1,Pong_Node).
```

Esta função está definida em dois casos (repare que a primeira definição de `ping` termina com `;`, em vez de `.` - isto diz ao Erlang que ainda há mais para completar a definição desta função).

A função é chamada com `3` como primeiro argumento. Como `3` não equivale a `0`, o processo executa o segundo caso, com `N` como argumento.

Este processo envia o par `{ping, self()}` ao processo dado por `{pong, Pong_Node}`, que segue a síntaxe `{nome_registado, nome_do_nodo}`. A função `self()` é usada para obter o *pid* do processo atual. Depois disto, o processo espera resposta, e repete este ciclo, enquanto `N` for maior que zero.

Quando `N` chega a zero, o primeiro caso é executado, enviando `finished` ao `{pong, Pong_Node}`, e terminando execução.

---

Se achar esta explicação incompleta, pode também dar uma olhada [no tutorial](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#id67009), que explica este mesmo programa.